# Pan Gesture Recognizer (increasing bar) swift

Tags: ios, swift

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8gRp.jpg

This image above is what i am trying to achieve. I have the design complete however the pan gesture functionality is not yet finished. What i would like to do is have the user slide up and down to adjust the levels of each column. I would like to designate half of the screen(splitting vertically) for the blue bars and the other half for red. If the user drags their finger upward on the right side of the screen, the red bars will increase and blue bars decrease(by decrease i mean "bars disappear"). Same works for if the user drags their finger upward on the left side. Also the opposite occurs if the user drags their finger downward, the bars will decrease on the side they are dragging on and the other side will increase.

Could you please give me some feedback to how i can approach this design. Written code or sudo code will be much appreciated!!

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to both of the bars and then just adjust the bar values based on the movement. Of course you need to first see which bar is behind the point where the gesture started. The bars can be bitmaps or UIBezierPaths. To make the changes look smooth just animate hiding/showing the bars (color or alpha change). More detailed sample would mean doing to the work for you, so you just need to figure out the rest by yourself.

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("onPan:"))
barBackgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

func onPan(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(barBackgroundView)

    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .Began:
            panStartPoint = point
        case .Changed:
            // Adjust the bars using panStartBarPoint.y + (point.y - panStartPoint.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I have a question: So I'm now able to detect pan gestures upward and downward, now to add each individual bar how should i do it? If i have a total of 10 red bars, should i create 10 variables and add each subview then just switch the hidden true and false based on the movement? Is there a better way?

Comment: Would it be wiser to copy the UIImageView that i have to produce the red bars @Tapani

Comment: You have several options. I would choose the first one.

1) Draw each bar in the drawRect function of your custom UIView.
2) Use NSBezierPath as a layer mask of you bar view and update the path to form one or more bars.
3) One UIImage for each bar